# Maintaining multiple projects which consume conan packages

Tags: conan

Background:

I have a Visual Studio solution(s) with multiple (50+) projects (libraries static/dynamic and final executables). There is internal Visual Studio reference mechanism used to comsume required libraries for particular executables. Of course each project uses external packages, there are "duplicates" like boost, gtest, there are also some "unique" references for only one or few projects.
What's more, libraries are used in other solutions (project sharing) to deploy other executables.

This is my general project structure:

```
MainDir
|
- DebugDlls (build output)
- Debug64Dlls (build output)
- ReleaseDlls (build output)
- Release64Dlls (build output)
- Libraries
  |
  - lib1
  - lib2
  - ...
- Executables
  |
  - exe1
  - exe2
  ...
```

---

I'm about to migrate from NuGet to conan as a dependency manager for external libraries since there are more ready to use conan packages that NuGet one and it's cross-platform. I'd like to do it project by project, dependency by dependency.

One global conan file to rule them all is not an option since each library has to be as standalone as possible so I'm able to simply grab one and use for new executable. What's more it would be impossible to track dependencies of particular library or executable.

My idea is to put a separate conanfile in each project and define dependencies.

1. Here is the first issue: I need some global/automatic management of common libraries like boost to not mix versions/variants and spare some time on version updates.

   - this one may be handled by a global file which defines reusable depndencies
   - is there something ready to use in conan, like template?
2. Second issue is to copy dlls from dependencies into proper `build output` so I'm able to execute the binaries.

   - this one should be fixable also by some global file with proper defines.
3. Third one is to execute `conan install` in each project

   - once again, a hand crafted script will do the job.

I was digging across the conan documentation but it's not very well organized and I was unable to find proper solution in my case. Maybe I missed something?

What would be the best approach here? Is there any build in conan mechanism for that (like CMake add_subdirectory). I would not like to reinvent the well if one already exists :)

I'm about to use conan 1.x

Comment: I would recommend to reconsider not using 1 conanfile to install all dependencies. If you are using the ``MSBuildDeps`` generator, it will generate 1 .props file for each different dependency, so you can add the specific dependencies for each subproject separately, while keeping global consistency of the common installed versions. Probably you need to test the MSBuildDeps integration first to understand how it works.

Comment: Copying the ``dlls`` might not be necessary. The ``MSBuildDeps`` generator will put things in the runtime path in the generated .props files, so .dlls are located inside the packages.

Comment: I'm playing with `MSBuildDeps` and since my executable is the C#, that uses some C++/CLI (where dependency is consumed, but not in C#), then C# project that runs knows nothing about variables added by conan.

Copying also allows running executable directly from file manager.

I need a while to rethink the one conan file approach.

Comment: If not, creating your own "generator", something forked from MSBuildDeps to automate the integration of C++ dependencies in the C# project could be a good approach, maybe better than restructuring the project with multiple conanfiles. It is possible with the ``python_requires`` feature, you put the code in a recipe, and you can reuse that code in other conanfiles.